# MySQL: (Nested / Sub) Queries on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I read some similar posts, but I am still having a hard time trying to come up with a couple of queries to select the records I need. Would anyone like to try to solve the two queries below, please? Thank you in advance.

```
  Slices Table  
 +--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
 |   id   |   model   |   type     |   status   |  print_time  |
 +--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
 |   01   |    01     |  Orient    |  Finished  |     100      |   # Orient Finished 
 |   02   |    01     |  Orient    |  Finished  |     120      |   # Estimate Finished 
 |   03   |    01     |  Estimate  |  Finished  |     70       |   # IGNORE  
 |   04   |    01     |  Estimate  |  Finished  |     90       |  
 |        |           |            |            |              |
 |   05   |    02     |  Orient    |  Finished  |     320      |   # Orient Finished
 |   06   |    02     |  Orient    |  Finished  |     240      |   # Estimate Slicing
 |   07   |    02     |  Estimate  |  Finished  |     260      |   # IGNORE  
 |   08   |    02     |  Estimate  |  Slicing   |     0        | 
 |        |           |            |            |              |
 |   09   |    03     |  Orient    |  Finished  |     560      |   # Orient Slicing
 |   10   |    03     |  Orient    |  Slicing   |     0        |   # Estimate Start
 |   11   |    03     |  Estimate  |  Start     |     0        |   # IGNORE  
 |   12   |    03     |  Estimate  |  Start     |     0        | 
 |        |           |            |            |              |
 |   13   |    04     |  Orient    |  Finished  |     480      |   # Orient Finished
 |   14   |    04     |  Orient    |  Finished  |     200      |   # Estimate Start
 |   15   |    04     |  Estimate  |  Start     |     0        |   # SELECT
 |   16   |    04     |  Estimate  |  Start     |     0        |   
 |        |           |            |            |              |
 |   17   |    05     |  Orient    |  Finished  |     560      |   # Orient Finished
 |   18   |    05     |  Orient    |  Finished  |     340      |   # Estimate Start
 |   19   |    05     |  Estimate  |  Start     |     0        |   # SELECT
 |   20   |    05     |  Estimate  |  Start     |     0        |   
 |        |           |            |            |              |
 |   21   |    06     |  Orient    |  Start     |     0        |   # Orient Start
 |   22   |    06     |  Orient    |  Start     |     0        |   # Estimate Start
 |   23   |    06     |  Estimate  |  Start     |     0        |   # IGNORE 
 |   24   |    06     |  Estimate  |  Start     |     0        |   
 +--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

First Query:

I need to select records from the same model id,
where type = Estimate and status = Start,
only when ALL of the same model id records of type = Orient have status = Finished

Desired result from first query:

```
 +--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
 |   id   |   model   |   type     |   status   |  print_time  |
 +--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
 |   15   |    04     |  Estimate  |  Start     |     0        |
 |   16   |    04     |  Estimate  |  Start     |     0        |
 |   19   |    05     |  Estimate  |  Start     |     0        |
 |   20   |    05     |  Estimate  |  Start     |     0        |
 +--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

Second Query:

As a second similar query, I need to select records
where type = Orient and status = Finished
only when ALL of the same model id records of type = Estimate have status = Start
and then order them by print time and show only the one with the lowest print time

Desired result from second query:

```
 +--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
 |   id   |   model   |   type     |   status   |  print_time  |
 +--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
 |   14   |    04     |  Orient    |  Finished  |     200      |
 |   18   |    05     |  Orient    |  Finished  |     340      |
 +--------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: You seem to have two questions, which is one too many for StackOverflow.